# Unable to return same double using Google Protocol Buffers from C# to C++ and back

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I'm trying to communicate between C# and C++ with varying amounts of success.

I am able to send a message between the two using reply/request, but the doubles that I am receiving are not correct.

For debugging purposes and understanding, I am currently running the following:

Clrzmq 3.0 rc1, Google ProtocolBuffer 2.5, Protobuf-csharp-port-2.4, ZeroMQ-3.2.3

.Proto

```
package InternalComm;

message Point 
{
    optional double x = 1;
    optional double y = 2;
    optional string label = 3;
}
```

server.cpp (the relevant part)

```
while (true) {
    zmq::message_t request;

    // Wait for next request from client
    socket.recv (&request);
    zmq::message_t reply (request.size());
    memcpy ((void*)reply.data(), request.data(), request.size());
    socket.send(reply);
}
```

client.cs (the relevant part)

```
public static Point ProtobufPoint(Point point)
    {
        Point rtn = new Point(0,0);
        using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
        {
            using (ZmqSocket requester = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ))
            {
                requester.Connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
                var p = InternalComm.Point.CreateBuilder().SetX(point.X).SetY(point.Y).Build().ToByteArray();

                requester.Send(p);

                string reply = requester.Receive(Encoding.ASCII);
                Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}", point);

                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reply);
                var message = InternalComm.Point.ParseFrom(bytes);
                rtn.X = message.X;
                rtn.Y = message.Y;

                Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", rtn);
            }
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

On the C# side, Point is a very simple struct. Just x and y properties.

Here is what I'm getting from my unit tests as a result of running the above code.

> Input (1.31616874365468, 4.55516872325469)
>   
>   Output (0.000473917985115791, 4.55516872323627)
>
> Input (274.120398471829, 274.128936418736) 
>   
>   Output (274.077917334613, 274.128936049925)
>
> Input (150.123798461987, 2.345E-12) 
>   
>   Output (145.976459594794, 1.11014954927532E-13)
>
> Input (150, 0) 
>   
>   Output (145.96875, 0)

I am thinking that the problem is my protobuf code is incorrect (doubtful this is a bug on Skeet's side). I am also running under the assumption that server.cpp is doing nothing to the message but returning it as is.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just to confirm: System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reply); is definitely a huge problem here. Protobuf data *is not ascii*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `requestor.Receive(Encoding.ASCII)` call is designed to receive a string, not a block of bytes.  You are asking the `ZmqSocket` instance to return the message as an ASCII string, which is highly likely to cause modifications to the content.  If you're sending a byte array, receive a byte array.

Try this:

```
int readSize;
byte[] reply = requester.Receive(null, out readSize);
var message = InternalComm.Point.ParseFrom(reply);
```

The `readSize` variable will contain the actual number of valid bytes in the received block, which may vary from the size of the `reply` array, so you may need to slice up the array to make it palatable to ProtoBuf.

Comment: To clarify, when you say slice up the array, do you mean break the message up into smaller pieces for the wire? Or receiving large message are better broken up for parsing?

Comment: Btw, this solved my problem. Going from byte to string was the issue.

Comment: @Elxx I haven't used ProtocolBuffer before yesterday, so I wasn't sure if it would be happy to read only the bytes it needed from the buffer and ignore the rest of the buffer's content.  Still not sure for that matter.  If you have 18 bytes worth of data in a 1024 byte buffer with other, possibly random data, does ProtocolBuffer work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

Why the ASCII --> bytes --> parsing step?  If you're parsing bytes, you should read bytes. If you're parsing text, you should read that.

Unnecessary charset-conversions look very likely to be erroneous.

Comment: Actually, thats the only way I found to get the reply message back into usable form. What would be your recommendation as a replacement? I agree that it looks troublesome...

Comment: Yes, reading raw bytes into a C# string type is a recipe for data corruption. I don't know ZeroMQ, but there must be a receive method that will give you raw bytes back.